# Adding a click event to el element and remove from the DOM in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

How can i add click event to my el elements in this case multiple li's. I'm trying to remove li from the dom on click, but the click event is not firing.

```
App.Views.ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : 'li',
    Wrapper : '#list_cntr ul',
    template : 'tmplItem',

    events : {
        'click li' : 'removeMe'
    },

    initialize : function() {

        this.render();
    },

    render : function() {
        $(this.Wrapper).prepend($(this.el).html(App.Templates[this.template](this.model.toJSON())));
    },

    removeMe : function() {
        var eventList = App.Collections.eventCollectionList;
        var eid = this.model.get('id');
        eventList.remove(eid);

       //How to remove the li?
    }

});
```

Comment: Does the parent `ul` have click event listeners? It might be intercepting the events and not bubbling them down to the `li`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
>
> [...] Omitting the selector causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

The `el` for your view is the `<li>` that you want a click handler on so you should be able to drop the selector in your `events`:

```
events : {
    'click' : 'removeMe'
},
```

That will bind `removeMe` to clicks on the `<li>` itself.

You're also setting `el: 'li'` when you want to say `tagName: 'li'`. The [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) property is your view's DOM element but `'li'` won't do anything useful. If you specify a `tagName` then Backbone will create the `<li>` for you and `this.el` will be the view's single `<li>`. This is probably where the strange "it looks like all the `<li>`s" behavior you're seeing comes from.

Your view should look more like this:

```
App.Views.ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    //...
    events : {
        'click' : 'removeMe'
    },
    //...
    removeMe : function() {
        var eventList = App.Collections.eventCollectionList;
        var eid = this.model.get('id');
        eventList.remove(eid);
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MTh57/

Comment: ok within removeMe i wrote console.log($(this)); but after i click a li it shows all the li's that are present within the ul instead of clicked one..

Comment: if i do console.log(this.el); i get the DOM of selected li but on console.log(this); it shows all the li objects

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. What happens if you add `this.remove()` to `removeMe`? That should remove the `<li>` you clicked on.

Comment: it seems to remove all the li's, i've totally given up on this.

Comment: @user1184100: Don't despair, I missed your `el` problem before, have a look at the update please.